# NoSQL injection - java server

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, nosql-injection

I am trying to create a java servlet with a NoSQL injection vulnerability. I've connected the servlet with MongoDB and check if the login info submitted by the user exists, I'm doing the next query:

```
String andQuery = "{$and: [{user: \""+u+"\"}, {password: \""+p+"\"}]}";
```

Where u is the user and p is the password given by the user.
For what I've seen this is correct, and the NoSQL injection should exist, bu I really dont kno how to prove it.

I've tried submitting with burp this:

```
username[$ne]=1&password[$ne]=1
```

But its not working, and when I check the content of u and p after I submitted that the content of both variables is null.
I dont have the servlet configured to receive json objects so I need a solition that doesn't imply send a json object with burp.

PD: I tryed also to insert something like this:

```
{\"$gt\":\"\" }
```

in the user and password fields but the result query is

```
{"$and": [{"user": "{\"$gt\":\"\" }"}, {"password": "{\"$gt\":\"\" }"}]}
```

I guess this doesn't work because the {"$gt":"" } is in quotes, ¿how can I do the servlet to be vulnarable and with which input it would be vulnerabel?

Comment: See https://blog.websecurify.com/2014/08/hacking-nodejs-and-mongodb

Comment: I was looking for a solution with a java server, not javascript

Comment: I think the injetion value for password and user should be in your case `"$gt\": \""`, since the opening and closing quotes are already there

Comment: I get this error: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Invalid JSON input. Position: 42. Character: '\'. I think it could be beacouse this line: FindIterable<org.bson.Document> cursor2 = collection.find(obj.parse(andQuery)); Meaby when it convert the string in the org object its when it adds the quotes. Is it right?

Comment: I meant the rar value `$gt": "`, how did the query look like

Comment: it doesn't work either. The error is: org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a name but found ':'